# Which PDF viewer for Linux supports going back and forward?

Tags: linux, pdf, linux-mint, pdf-reader

I use Alt-arrow to go back and forward very often in browser, IDE, etc. But the standard PDF viewer in Linux Mint lacks this function. What can I use instead (preferably not Adobe Reader)?

Answer (score 0):

Evince (the GNOME document reader) has this function. (In version 3.6 or older, you have to add the buttons via *Edit → Toolbar*.)

[image]

Comment: Hmm, that's weird, but I found out that Evince is the default PDF viewer in Mint and it doesn't have this feature on my system. I couldn't find it in the settings also. It even looks differently from your screenshot.

Comment: @lizarisk: The screenshot is from Evince 3.8, but I'm quite sure that it had Back/Forward buttons in 3.6 and earlier versions as well.